# I'm running a convolution over an image with a randomized kernel. How to account for the added depth of RGB values?

Tags: python, image, math, convolution

I am trying to run a convolution with a randomized kernel over a image list created with PIL.Image. Doing it on my own worked, it's just very slow (0.00016 seconds per pixel, but that adds up). Here is the code for that:

```
def convolve(list_, kernel, x_pos, y_pos):
    """
    Runs a convolution given a image list, kernel, and pixel coordinates (within the given list).

    Returns a tuple holding the RGB values of the finished convolution.
    """
    # defines a slice of the main list "l"
    cut = []
    for i in range(KERNEL_SIZE**2):
        ny_pos = floor(i/KERNEL_SIZE)-padding
        nx_pos = i % KERNEL_SIZE-padding
        cut.append(list_[y_pos+ny_pos][x_pos+nx_pos])
    conv = [tuple(y*kernel[0][x] for y in cut[x]) for x in range(len(cut))]
    # returns processed rgb tuple.
    return tuple(map(sumround, zip(*conv)))
```

The problem is, running this over any decently sized image is very slow. I was thinking of using fftconvolve from SciPy but it won't work because of the tuples.

How would I convolve a 1d list to a 2d list? I was wondering if flattening the original list, running the convolution on that, and packing it back up to RGB might work?

Thanks for any help!

-=-

Tried: Convolving the two arrays with np.convolve, scipy.signal.convolve, scipy.signal.fftconvolve, and scipy.signal.convolve2d.

Expected: Successful convolution of RGB values within the original list given a randomized kernel.

Experienced: Errors.

Comment: Why didn't `numpy.convolve` work?  Isn't it the same operation you're doing?  You can't hope to improve the performance by doing a pixel at a time in Python code.

Comment: @Tim Roberts It could be that the image data wasn't being processed in a numpy array, but rather in the format of `[(R,G,B), (R,G,B), ...]`. If I shouldn't process the convolution one pixel at a time, how else should I run a convolution in this way?

Comment: PIL can deliver you the channels separately, as three 2D arrays.  You can convolve and clamp, then PIL can glue them back together into an image.

Comment: This will work, thank you!